# Prerouting marked packets to the loopback interface inside a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, iptables, bridge, ebtables

Before I describe my question or more particulary my problem in more detail, I want to first depict my basic approach:

Basicly what I'm trying to do is to create an [inline on a linux bridge](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/4.2.x/admin/transparent-proxy/bridge.en.html) inside a docker container (operation system is alpine). For that I created a testing environment containing an example client and server via docker and implemented those container inside GNS3 for creating the desired network topology: server <--> bridge <--> client.

And here is the problem: the bridging is working fine (both client and server can ping eachother), but the prerouting of the marked packets to the loopback interface by [lifting it up from the ethernet layer to the ip layer](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/examples/basic.html#ex_redirect) (so that I can use iptables rules on them) inside the docker container isn't working as expected (no incomimg packets on interface lo).

So my question is, whether this is a general problem from docker or from my configuration?